# get key and value from json in array with check

Tags: json, jq

I had a json

```
[
    {
        "name": "type1",
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataA1",
            "set1": "dataA2"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "type2",
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataB1",
            "set2": "dataB2"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "null",
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataC1",
            "set2": "dataC2"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "type4",
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataD1",
            "set2": "dataD2"
        }
    }
]
```

This is a long json so instead I thought to make it like this.

```
{
    "type1": {
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataA1",
            "set2": "dataA2"
        }
    },
    null: {
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataB1",
            "set2": "dataB2"
        }
    },
    "type3": {
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataC1",
            "set2": "dataC2"
        }
    },
    "type4": {
        "type": "string",
        "values": {
            "set1": "dataD1",
            "set2": "dataD2"
        }
    }
}
```

So, I wanna ask if this is actually good or should I use the old one. And if this one is better
I previously used `jq '.[] | .name, .type' file.json`

then how to get output
like this with the new json

```
"key"
"type"
"key"
"type"
"key"
"type"
```

so output becomes

```
type1
string
type2
string
# the type3 and its type is not needed cause its null
type4
string
```

also, some values name are null, so I don't want the string as null too.

Comment: The second JSON is not valid. `parse error: Object keys must be strings at line 9, column 9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_entries`, then select the non-null keys and extract the values:

```
jq 'to_entries | map(select(.key != "null"))[] | (.key, .value.type)' < file2.json
```

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea as in [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734923/116858) but acting on the original JSON document without transforming the `name` keys' values into keys:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map( select(.name != "null") | .name, .type )[]'  file
type1
string
type2
string
type4
string
```

This extracts all the entries in the top-level array whose `name` values are not the string `null`. It then pulls out the `name` and `type` values from the remaining entries.

In general, it makes little sense to use *data* as the value of keys in JSON, which is why I opted for working with the original file.