# numbering to each jq output

Tags: bash, jq

I have a JSON file

```json
{
    "fieldA": {"fieldData": "XYZ"}
    "fieldB": {"fieldData": "PQR"}
    "fieldC": {"fieldData": null}
    "fieldD": {"fieldData": "DEF"}
```

I used `jq`

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | if .value.fieldData != null then .key, .value.fieldData else empty end'
```

to print the data like this

```
fieldA
XYZ
fieldB
PQR
fieldD
DEF
```

Now I want to get index with this also, but ignoring the null value.

```
1
fieldA
XYZ
2
fieldB
PQR
# see the 3rd field is ignored completely and 3 is given for the 4th field.
3
fieldD
DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input JSON document is valid, like the following:

```json
{
   "fieldA": { "fieldData": "XYZ" },
   "fieldB": { "fieldData": "PQR" },
   "fieldC": { "fieldData": null },
   "fieldD": { "fieldData": "DEF" }
}
```

Then you can start your `jq` expression by removing the parts that have a `fieldData` value that is `null`:

```bash
jq 'map_values(select(.fieldData != null))' file
```

To then access the index of each key in the resulting object, we can use `to_entries` *twice* and extract it along with the other data we're interested in:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map_values(select(.fieldData != null)) | to_entries | to_entries | map(.key+1, .value.key, .value.value.fieldData)[]' file
1
fieldA
XYZ
2
fieldB
PQR
3
fieldD
DEF
```

We use `to_entries` twice to access the index of the keys within the original object.

Note that the order of keys in JSON objects is not necessarily fixed.  If you need a fixed ordering of things in a JSON structure, use an array instead. Maybe something like

```json
[
    { "name": "fieldA", "fieldData": "XYZ" },
    { "name": "fieldB", "fieldData": "PQR" },
    { "name": "fieldC", "fieldData": null },
    { "name": "fieldD", "fieldData": "DEF" }
]
```

---

Using your original data from your previous related question ([get key and value from json in array with check](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734915/get-key-and-value-from-json-in-array-with-check)):

```bash
jq -r 'map(select(.name != "null")) | to_entries | map(.key+1, .value.name, .value.type)[]'  file
```

or

```bash
jq -r 'map(select(.name != "null") | [.name, .type]) | to_entries | map(.key+1, .value[])[]'  file
```

which is slightly closer to my answer to your other question.

Note the lack of initial call to `to_entries` compared to the above since we now don't have *data in keys* and therefore do not have the investigate the keys themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works perfectly.

Comment: @decipher I have updated my answer in response to you changing the data in the question.